# Regexp: find characters in concrete string

Tags: regex

I have something like this:

```
   public function selector($selected = null, $name = 'type_id', array $default = null)
    {
        return view('@admin/defaul/tSelector' <-- slashes from this string , [
            'name' => $name,
            'id' => $name,
            'defaultValue' => $default,
        ]);
        someFunc('@someText/defaul/tSelector');

        //'some/text/'
        //comment with 'some/path/'
        'a/b'

        view('@aaa/bbb/ccc/ddddddd <-- slashes from this string
dddddddd/eee/ffff'); <-- slashes from this string

    }
```

I want to find all slashes in concrete strings — that used **only** in view() functions. it means, that other slashes not need.

I do this, but it return all slahes.

For example, I need slashes from functions with name *'view'* name:
`view('@admin/defaul/tSelector',` and `view('@aaa/bbb/ccc/ddddddddddddddd/eee/ffff');`

https://regex101.com/r/xXNuIj/2

Comment: Please, show us what you expect as response of the regex

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but I think what you need is the [tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php).

Comment: @olibiaz,  I edited question

Comment: In some string unknown quantity of slashes. Yes, i want to change  slashes to dots in future, on second step. But it's other story) Now, I need to get all slashes in string into  the all view() functions.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will look for the view function calls and return a subgroup with the value of the first parameter string:

```
/view\(\s*'([^']*)'/
```

You can use `preg_match_all` to match all occurrences in a string, and then operate on the string however you desire. (For example, split it by slashes.)

```
<?php

$data = "public function selector(\$selected = null, \$name = 'type_id', array \$default = null)".
    "{".
        "return view('@admin/defaul/tSelector' , [".
        "    'name' => \$name,".
        "    'id' => \$name,".
        "    'defaultValue' => \$default,".
        "]);".
        "someFunc('@someText/defaul/tSelector');".

        "//'some/text/'".
        "//comment with 'some/path/'".
        "'a/b'".

        "view('@aaa/bbb/ccc/ddddddddddddddd/eee/ffff');".
    "}";

if(preg_match_all("/view\(\s*'([^']*)'/", $data, $matches)){
    foreach($matches[1] as $view){
        var_dump(explode("/", $view));
        echo('<br>');
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, my friend, but I will use regexp outside of php, etc. On this, I need a solution on native regexp.